# How to manage events in converse.js xmpp library

Tags: javascript, events, callback, converse.js

Im actually developing a custom ERP for my business company and i need implement xmpp web based chat applicatión using **Converse.js**.

But i can't find any solution to manage events callback's with the api.

According to the documentation, the following syntax should be used:

`_converse.api.listen.on('message', function (messageXML) { ... });`

**OR**

`converse.api.listen.on('message', function (messageXML) { ... });`

But "converse.api" it's undefinied

Converse.js version **6.0.1**

I hope your valuable help.

*Sorry for my bad english*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conerse.js has a public (i.e. globally accessible) API, which is available via the [converse](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/api/converse.html) global. The most used method there would be [converse.initialize](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/api/converse.html#.initialize).

Most API methods are however restricted to the private (i.e. closured) [_converse](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/api/-_converse.html) object (note the leading underscore) and is available via [_converse.api](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/api/-_converse.api.html).

You can only access `_converse.api` if you [register a plugin](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/plugin_development.html#registering-a-plugin).

For example:

```
converse.plugins.add('myplugin', {

    initialize: function () {
        // This method gets called once converse.initialize has been called
        // and the plugin itself has been loaded.

        // Inside this method, you have access to the closured
        // _converse object as an attribute on "this".
        // E.g. this._converse
        const { api } = this._converse;
        api.listen.on('message', function (messageXML) { ... });
    }
});
```